# How to style text as bold in facebook feed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I am developing an app where the user can share some text on his facebook account. I tried to bold some sentence using html () and using **. But nothing worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That Kind of features still not provided By FaceBook API Integration Team.

Alternatively  you can create custom url pass through link in  url

```
 ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("your url"))
    .build();
```

Read more for more details [Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame